# What is shallow key transformation

Tags: django, security, cryptography, key

I was reading about CVE-2019-14234 Detail. There it is mentioned about shallow key transformation. Can you please tell me what is shallow key transformation. It would be better if someone can explain about this CVE also. Please ignore this if this question is at wrong place.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is about IT security (https://security.stackexchange.com).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

My understanding is that "shallow key transformation" refers to the process of converting a key with double underscores like `Dog.objects.filter(data__owner__name='Bob')` to the appropriate SQL syntax, something like `... WHERE "data" -> 'owner' -> 'name' = 'Bob'`

The security vulnerability that this CVE refers to was that you could craft a key that would be passed to the database as is, e.g.:

```
JSONModel.objects.filter(**{
    """field__test' = '"a"') OR 1 = 1 OR ('d""": 'x',
})
```